# Pass callbacks from parent state to child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I pass a callback from parent state to child component when I am using the ui-router state?

Example

```
$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    url: '/',
    component: components.intro.name,
  })
    .state('main.root', {
      url: '/main/',
      component: components.main.name,
    })
```

`main` component would have a method, `this.callback`. I want to pass this into the `main.root` state. From my testing, the child state is only able to receive the resolves?

Comment: http://thankcoder.com/questions/e8fbd/angular-ui-router-pass-resolve-to-child-onenter

Comment: Hi GANI thanks for linking that. This question is different from the one you linked. I am trying to pass a callback declared in the intro component. It is not a resolve.

Answer (score 0):

[I made a Plunker to show the implementation of your question.](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZXuWcD9o3DK1t9hNo0Xm)

Only ui-router 1.0.3^ has the functionality you're seeking. Define the callback in the parent component's controller:

```
angular.module('app')
.component('main', {
  controller: function() {
    this.handleClickInParent = function () {
      // this is the cb we're going to pass to the child
      alert('Callback got clicked.');
    };
  },   
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Parent Template: main</p>

      <ui-view on-button-click=$ctrl.handleClickInParent></ui-view>
    </div>
  `
});
```

Look at the template. The callback is passed to ui-view, where children are rendered. When the child component is active, it will receive the `$ctrl.handleClickInParent` callback. However, the child component must be "listening" for the callback:

```
angular.module('app')
.component('nestedChild', {
  bindings: {
    // this binding is where the child is "listening"
    onButtonClick: '<'
  },
  controller: function() {
     console.log(this.onButtonClick);
     // alert fn from parent
     // the child template can access this callback as $ctrl.onButtonClick()
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Child Template: nestedChild</p>
      <button ng-click=$ctrl.onButtonClick()>Click me to trigger passed callback</button>
    </div>
`,
});
```

#### Other Examples

There's a good example on how to migrate ui-router to components for Angular 1.5, [here](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#routed-parentchild-component-communication). They use '&' for the function binding instead, but I find the one-way '<' symbol to be much simpler.